# Extract month, day and year from date regex

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have a date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. But, depending on what day or month, there is no guarantee that the  "mm/dd" part will necessarily have two digits. So the dates may be:

```
11/12/2014
```

or

```
6/12/2014
```

or

```
11/5/2014
```

In all of the above situations I will need to be able to extract each value for `mm`, `dd`, and `yyyy` so I can do something like this for a calculation:

```
Month = regex that returns month part.
Day = regex that returns day part
Year = regex that returns 4 digits year part.
```

This `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}`  matches the whole thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: You just need to capture the groups in the regex, as per the linked example.

Comment: Also, {1,2} instead of {2}

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, because not only is it narrower in scope, it has one possible solution (using **.split**) that doesn't apply to the other question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Regexp Solution

The proper regex matching all of your dates is: `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}`. Notation
`{n,m}` is called **limiting repetition** and in this case `\d{n,m}` means "between n and m digits (inclusive)". You can read more about that here: [Limiting Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).

If you want to create matching groups, use "(" and ")" (parentheses). Addiitonally, in JavaScript, you have to to escape `/` with `\` and thus your regexp is: `/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/`

You can use `exec` function of the regexp to match strings against it. It returns an array containing the matched text as the first element and then one item for each of the matched groups.

You can find out more on MDN [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) or see this example below:

```
const datePattern = /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/;
const date = datePattern.exec("11/12/2014"); // ["11/12/2014", "11", "12", "2014"]
```

**Note:** If an invalid string is passed (not matching the regular expression) `exec` function will return `null`. It's an easy way to do brief validation of users' input or data.

### Alternative solution

Alternatively you can simply split the strings:

```
"11/12/2014".split('/'); // ["11", "12", "2014"]
```

But this will work regardless of what the string actually contains (it might contain string `"ba/tm/an"` and split will still return an array with three elements). For this reason, Regexp is probably a better fit if you want to validate the dates.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation and the "split" alternative. Of course I overlooked that again in my eagerness to use a regular expression :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var str = "11/6/2014";
var match = str.match(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/);

console.log(match[1]); // => "11"
console.log(match[2]); // => "6"
console.log(match[3]); // => "2014"
```

alternatively you can create a date object:

```
var date = new Date("11/6/2014");

var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();

console.log(year);  // => 2014
console.log(month); // => 11
console.log(day);   // => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to extract the pieces, just use `split`. I used regex to allow forward or backward slashes.

```
var date = "1/10/2014"
, dateParts = date.split(/\\|\//)
, month = dateParts[0]
, day = dateParts[1]
, year = dateParts[2];
```